# How to prevent redirect_to_login from targeting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Tags: django

So in general when a user logs in, my app redirects him to `dashboard-overview`:

```
# settings.py

# Login and Logout target routes
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard-overview'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

However for a specific case I want the user to be redirected to 'calculator-page' using a [helper function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#helper-functions) which doesn't work as the user is again redirected to the value of `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

```
# views.py

def render_calculator(request, slug):
    """
    Renders the calculator page
    """
    # Check for the user being authenticated
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect_to_login('calculator-page')
   
        # routes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=calculator-page which looks fine, 
        # but then it fails after login to re-route as specified and sends to
        # 'dashboard-overview' again

    else:

        club_obj = Offer.objects.get(club__slug=slug)

        # Create Context
        context = {
            'club_obj': club_obj,
        }

        return render(request, 'core/calculator.html', context)
```

```
# urls.py 

from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views
from applications.user import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [

    # Login View
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),

    # Sign Up
    path('signup/', user_views.signup, name='signup'),

]
```

```
# template user/login.html

{% extends 'user/user_frame.html' %}
{% load static %}

<!-- Styles -->
{% block styles %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/user_frame.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endblock styles %}


{% block form %}

    <div class="logo-container"><a href="/" style="margin: 0"><img src="{% static 'images/logo_negative_text.svg' %}" class="logo-image"></a></div>

    <div class="form-container">

        <!-- form headline -->
        <h1 class="form-headline">Login to your Farena Account</h1>
        <!-- form -->
        <form class="form" method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="error-wrapper">
                <div class="errors">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="email-wrapper field-wrapper">
                <div class="tag name-tag">{{ form.username.label }}*</div>
                <div class="input">{{ form.username }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="password-wrapper field-wrapper">
                <div class="tag">{{ form.password.label }}*</div>
                <div class="input">{{ form.password }}</div>
                <a href="/password_change/"><div class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</div></a>
            </div>
            <!-- submit button -->
            <button class="login-button" type="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <a href="/signup"><div class="account-info">No account yet? Sign Up!</div></a>

{% endblock form %}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom login view/template?

Comment: @solarissmoke yes I do

Comment: That is likely where the problem is - show us the code for the view and its template.

Comment: @solarissmoke added to the post. The view is default, template is custom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your template for the login view - you're missing the `next` form field that tells Django where to redirect the user after they have logged in. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) for sample template code for this view.

Specifically, you need to add this inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
```

That's missing right now which means Django will always just default to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

Comment: So cool, thanks!